# Weird issue with JWT token with web app in Azure

Tags: oauth, jwt, claims-based-identity, azure-web-app-service

I have 2 web apps setup in azure, both with the same clientids setup with oauth middleware. Both use the same Azure AD, with the same user I get a token and on one webapp I get a claimsprincipal but on the other one I get a windowsprincipal. Why could this be?

Comment: Are you using the [OpenIdConnect middleware](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect) for authentication or the build-in [App Service authentication / authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) and [configure your app use AAD login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication)?

Comment: AFAIK, windowsprincipal is talking about the window authentication. Please provide more details about how did you implement the authentication and the project type of your application (Web API, website,etc.). Moreover, you could attach some code snippets for us to better understand your scenario.

Comment: I found the issue, this bit was swallowing the real exception being thrown in my code, and returning it as a 401, I've added a catch to it:

Comment: Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnValidateIdentity = async identityContext =>